# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

hi i got issues in this code any help?

```
client.on("message", message => { 
  if(message.content.startsWith(prefix+"test")) {
      
let json = require('./json.json')
      
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(json.channel);
let msg = channel.messages.fetch(json.msg);

let embed = msg.embeds[0];

embed.addField("User: ", message.author.username, true)


msg.edit({ embeds: [ embed ] });
  }
});
```

ERROR

```
let embed = msg.embeds[0];
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

I want to add fields to that embed msg by the command but i got this error

Comment: Have you tried some basic debugging, like checking what the value of `msg` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextChannel.messages.fetch` returns a Promise. So you have to put your code inside `.then` or use async/await.
So the code would be:

```js
client.on("message", message => { 
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}test`)) {
    let json = require('./json.json');
    let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(json.channel);
    channel.messages.fetch(json.msg).then(msg => {
      let embed = msg.embeds[0];
      embed.addField("User: ", message.author.username, true);
      msg.edit({ embeds: [embed] });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: it now says DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Comment: Just use .edit(embed) on v12